# Project Euler 81 in Python

Tags: python

In the 5 by 5 matrix below, the minimal path sum from the top left to the bottom right, by only moving to the right and down, is indicated in bold red and is equal to 2427.

**131** 673 234 103 18

**201**  **96**  **342**    965 150

630 803 **746**  **422**  **111**

537 699 497 121 **956**

805 732 524 37  **331**

Find the minimal path sum, in matrix.txt (right click and 'Save Link/Target As...'), a 31K text file containing a 80 by 80 matrix, from the top left to the bottom right by only moving right and down.

Remark: I think they did mistake, when they mark the way http://projecteuler.net/problem=81

```
import numpy as np

matrix0 = [ map(int, row.split()) for row in open('matrix.txt')]

matrix=np.arange(6400).reshape(80,80)

for i in range(80):
    for j in range(80):
        matrix[i, j]=0

for i in range(80):
    for j in range(80):
        matrix[i, j]=matrix0[i][j]

sum=matrix[0,0]

k=0
n=0
while (k+n)<158:
    for i in range(k, k+1):
        for j in range(n, n+1):
            if i!=79 and j!=79:
                if matrix[i+1, j]<=matrix[i, j+1]:
                    sum=sum+matrix[i+1, j]
                    k=i+1
                    n=j
                else:
                    sum+=matrix[i, j+1]
                    k=i
                    n=j+1
            elif i==79:
                sum+=matrix[i, j+1]
                k=i
                n=j+1
            elif j==79:
                sum+=matrix[i+1, j]
                k=i+1
                n=j                 

print sum
```

When I use this code for the matrix 5x5 like in problem it gives me correct answer. I can't understand why it doesn't work on bigger matrix?

Answer (score 5):

Because you're not performing the search properly.  The problem is asking for the overall least cost path, so you want an A* search or Dijkstra's algorithm.  A simple one pass check for lowest branch at each node won't cut it.

Comment: For an 80x80 matrix you could use the Floyd as well, just wait a little longer :)

Comment: Because it just so happens that the naive algorithm that you are using happens to work on the example matrix.  Consider instead the matrix: `[[001, 002, 001, 001], [001, 002, 001, 001], [001, 002, 001, 001], [001, 999, 999, 001]]`.  The algorithm you have would take you down, (001 vs 002), down (001 vs 002), down (001 vs 002).  Then right 3 times (999, 999, 001).  Whereas a more intelligent algorithm would find the lower cost routes that have some locally suboptimal choices.

Comment: ok, i got it! I think i didn't understand the problem properly. In problem condition, they didn't have mistake!!! I'm going to learn this algorithms

Comment: Well, you seem to be new around here, so if you found this answer useful please upvote and accept it.

Comment: i don't think the best way to solve the problem is any shortest path algorithm, there's quite a obvious  DP model.

Comment: @Marcus Sure, but there's a more challenging version of the problem that can be done with shortest-path but not with DP. May as well learn how to solve that one too.

Answer (score 0):

I get correct answer.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun Jul 31 02:53:03 2022

@author: burak
"""
"""
Path sum: two ways
Problem 81
In the 5 by 5 matrix below, the minimal path sum from the top left to the bottom right,
by only moving to the right and down, is indicated in bold red and is equal to 2427.

Find the minimal path sum from the top left to the bottom right by only moving right 
and down in matrix.txt (right click and "Save Link/Target As..."), a 31K text file 
containing an 80 by 80 matrix.
"""
import numpy as np
with open('/home/burak/Downloads/p081_matrix.txt') as f:
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        a = f.read().splitlines()
        b = []
        for i in range(len(a)):
            bi = a[i].split(",")
            b.append(bi)
        a = np.array(b)
        v_, h_ = a.shape
        verticies1 = np.ones((v_,h_))*np.inf    
        verticies1[0][0] = 0
        i, j, h, v = 0, 0, 0, 0
        adjacents = []
        while i < v_:
            while j < h_:
                if i == 0 and j == 0:
                    verticies1[i][j] = int(a[i][j])
                elif i == 0 and j < h_:
                    verticies1[i][j] = int(a[i][j]) + verticies1[i][j - 1]
                elif i < v_ and j < h_:
                    verticies1[i][j] = int(a[i][j]) + min(verticies1[i][j - 1],verticies1[i - 1][j])
                elif i == v_ - 1 and j == h_ - 1:
                    verticies1[i][j] = int(a[i][j]) + min(verticies1[i - 1][j], verticies1[i][j - 1])
                j += 1
            j = 0
            i += 1
                
        print(verticies1[h_ - 1][v_ - 1])
    f.close()
```